# logparser SELECT clause: Syntax Error: unknown field 'DateTime'

Tags: sql, logparser

I have a problem. I created a Log Parser SQL Query that needs to retrieve Resultsets from .LOG file that has no Column Header. I used ParseIT Version 3.0. The problem there is Token inside the source file that I query called DateTime, but when I try to call the query from command line using Logparser.exe, I get the following error: `Error: SELECT clause: Syntax Error: unknown field 'DateTime'`.

Here is sample of the records from the Source. LOG File:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:
 collapse;width:1220pt" width="1626">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:6107;width:125pt" width="167" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:1097;width:23pt" width="30" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:7094;width:146pt" width="194" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:2816;width:58pt" width="77" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:15762;width:323pt" width="431" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:5814;width:119pt" width="159" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt; width: 125pt" width="167">
        Thread-47</td>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 23pt" width="30">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 146pt" width="194">5/21/2014 
        02:47:43:000812 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1" style="width: 58pt" width="77">
        1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 323pt" width="431">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 119pt" width="159">
        midtierConnection()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">checkDDPRequest()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">checkDDPRequest()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">run()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">run()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">doDDPSend()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">doDDPSend()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">doDDPSend()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">doDDPSend()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.ConnectionBase</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">setState()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(P)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">send()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">run()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">writeDDPResponse()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">writeDDPResponse()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">writeDDPResponse()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">checkDDPRequest()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-38</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">run()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Total 
        Memory: 16,318,464</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Free Memory:<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;
        </span>6,415,584</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-47</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:44:000953 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">midtierConnection()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:44:000953 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">checkDDPRequest()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:44:000953 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">checkDDPRequest()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:44:000953 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">run()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:44:000953 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">run()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:44:000953 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">doDDPSend()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:44:000953 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">doDDPSend()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">doDDPSend()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">doDDPSend()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.ConnectionBase</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">setState()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(P)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">send()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">run()<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">writeDDPResponse()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">writeDDPResponse()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">writeDDPResponse()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">checkDDPRequest()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Thread-12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">(W)</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">5/21/2014 02:47:45:000015 PM</td>
        <td align="right" class="auto-style1">1.4007E+12</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">run()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Total 
        Memory: 16,318,464</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">
        <td class="auto-style1" height="20" style="height: 15.0pt;">Free Memory:<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;
        </span>7,101,416</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That shows the text at Tab-Separated-Value TSV or TEXTLINE Format as below:

```
Thread-47   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM    1400698063812   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    midtierConnection() midtierConnection() Constructor
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM    1400698063812   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    checkDDPRequest()   New Incoming Request
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM    1400698063812   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    checkDDPRequest()   Incoming Request Length = 493
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM    1400698063812   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    run()               Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 API: ChangeBoxStatus Sending the request
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM    1400698063812   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    run()   Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 Incoming: *<transaction SSID="ESP-CPEINVENTORY"><apiname>ChangeBoxStatus</apiname><comcorp>4418</comcorp><opr>CG7</opr><bnumb>MA1410EJT253</bnumb><bxstatus>B</bxstatus><delboxpassword></delboxpassword><tech_number></tech_number><code_of_day>790</code_of_day><bypass_delete_scheme></bypass_delete_scheme><bypass_
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM    1400698063812   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection    doDDPSend()         Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 API: ChangeBoxStatus Writing the request to socket
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000812 PM    1400698063812   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection    doDDPSend()         Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 API: ChangeBoxStatus Waiting for the response
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection    doDDPSend()         Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 API: ChangeBoxStatus Data for response length = **0000193**
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection    doDDPSend()         Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 API: ChangeBoxStatus Response Data Fully Read
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.ConnectionBase   setState()  Setting connection state: 5
Thread-38   (P) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.ddpConnection    send()              Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 API: ChangeBoxStatus Origination: ContactConnection: 24.40.42.35 Time: 32 Total Time: 32
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    run()               Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 API: ChangeBoxStatus Getting the response
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    writeDDPResponse()  Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 API: ChangeBoxStatus Writing the response data
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    writeDDPResponse()  Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 Outgoing : *<?xml version="1.0"?><transaction><apiname>ChangeBoxStatus</apiname><errorcode>0</errorcode><errordescription/><transaction_status>Task Complete</transaction_status></transaction>*
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    writeDDPResponse()  Match!!! Host: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP367 Connection: Sys2_DatB_56639_DP3670083 req-resp API : ChangeBoxStatus==ChangeBoxStatus Corp : 04418==00000 House : 000000==000000
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    checkDDPRequest()   Connection closed by remote host
Thread-38   (W) 5/21/2014 02:47:43:000844 PM    1400698063844   com.dstsystems.awd.hostmanager.servers.ddp.midtierConnection    run()   midtierConnection: New Request: Thread-38
Total Memory: 16,318,464
Free Memory:  6,415,584
```

All I need to extract the Date and Time in two separate Columns. The First will be called Date and the other called Time.  I used ParseIT with the following SQL Query

`SELECT Date, QUANTIZE(Time,60) AS LogTime, APIName, Count(*) AS TotalHits, SUBSTR(Strings,ADD(INDEX_OF(Strings,'Host:'),5) ,22) AS BillingFrom, SUBSTR(Strings,ADD(INDEX_OF(Strings,'Connection:'),11) ,22) AS BILLINGTo, AVG(DIV(TO_REAL(TotalTime),1000)) AS AvgSec USING EXTRACT_TOKEN(FileName,2,'\\') AS Server, EXTRACT_TOKEN(DateTime, 0, ' ') AS TempDate, EXTRACT_TOKEN(DateTime, 1, ' ') AS TempTime, EXTRACT_TOKEN(DateTime, 2, ' ') AS Meridiem, EXTRACT_TOKEN(TempDate, 0, '/') AS TempMonth, EXTRACT_TOKEN(TempDate, 1, '/') AS TempDay, EXTRACT_TOKEN(TempDate, 2, '/') AS Year, CASE STRLEN(TempMonth) WHEN 1 THEN STRCAT('0', TempMonth) ELSE TempMonth END AS Month, CASE STRLEN(TempDay) WHEN 1 THEN STRCAT('0', TempDay) ELSE TempDay END AS Day, STRCAT(STRCAT(STRCAT(STRCAT(Year, '-'), Month), '-'), Day) AS Date, REPLACE_STR(TempTime, STRCAT(':', EXTRACT_SUFFIX (TempTime,0,':')), '') AS  TimeNoMilliSec, EXTRACT_TOKEN(TimeNoMilliSec, 0, ':') AS Hour, STRCAT(Hour,Meridiem) AS HourMeridiem, CASE HourMeridiem WHEN '12AM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, '00') WHEN '01PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) WHEN '02PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) WHEN '03PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) WHEN '04PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) WHEN '05PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) WHEN '06PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) WHEN '07PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) WHEN '08PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) WHEN '09PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12)))  WHEN '10PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) WHEN '11PM' THEN REPLACE_STR(TimeNoMilliSec, Hour, TO_STRING(ADD(TO_INT(Hour), 12))) ELSE TimeNoMillisec END AS MilitaryTime, TO_TIMESTAMP(MilitaryTime,'hh:mm:ss') AS Time, ADD(INDEX_OF(Strings, ' API:'), 6) AS API_StartValue, EXTRACT_TOKEN(SUBSTR(Strings, API_StartValue), 0, ' ' ) AS API_Value, ADD(INDEX_OF(Strings, ' API : '), 7) AS API_2_StartValue,  EXTRACT_TOKEN(SUBSTR(Strings, API_2_StartValue), 0, '==' ) AS API_2_Value, COALESCE(API_Value, SUBSTR(Strings, ADD(INDEX_OF(Strings, '<apiname>'),  9), SUB(INDEX_OF(Strings, '</apiname>'),  ADD(INDEX_OF (Strings, '<apiname>'), 9)) ),  API_2_Value, EXTRACT_TOKEN(Command,0, '(' ) ) AS APIName, TO_INT(SUBSTR(Strings, ADD(INDEX_OF(Strings, 'Total Time: '), 12)) ) AS TotalTime, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 500) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _.5s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 500) WHEN 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _1s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 500) WHEN 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _1.5s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 500) WHEN 1500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _2s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 500) WHEN 2000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _2.5s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 500) WHEN 2500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _3s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 3000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _4s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 4000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _5s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 5000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _6s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 6000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _7s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 7000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _8s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 8000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _9s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 9000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _10s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _11s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 11000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _12s,  CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 12000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _13s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 13000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _14s, CASE QUANTIZE(TotalTime, 1000) WHEN 14000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _15s, CASE ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(_.5s, _1s), _1.5s), _2s), _2.5s), _3s), _4s), _5s), _6s), _7s), _8s), _9s), _10s), _11s), _12s), _13s), _14s), _15s) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _15Gs FROM D:\Projects\IIS_Logs\Servers\AQuA_HM\PACDCAQuAHM02\*.log WHERE Type = '(P)' GROUP BY BillingFrom, BILLINGTo, Date, LogTime, APIName ORDER BY Date, LogTime, APIName`

with the following command to automate it:

```
logparser -e:10000 -iw:ON -i:TSV -stats:off file:PACDCAQuAHM02.sql -o:csv>>PACDCAQuAHM02.csv
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: SELECT clause: Syntax Error: unknown field 'DateTime'
```

So, How Can I resolve that Issue.

Comment: You might want to add line breaks to your query so people don;t have to scroll horizontally to find all occurrences of "DateTime".

Comment: I put the SQL Statement Query are regulat text in Bold Effect.

Comment: By the way if I change from TSV to TEXTLINE in the input for logparser, still gives the same error message.

Comment: e.g. logparser -e:10000 -iw:ON -i:TEXTLINE -stats:off file:PACDCAQuAHM02.sql -o:csv>>PACDCAQuAHM02.csv

Comment: Your command suggests that you're asking the TSV input format to parse the first line of the log as the header line; so it all depends on whether that first line states a field named 'DateTime' or not.

Comment: It worked fine with ParseIT because DateTime is reserved token or keyword in that tool but it is not recognized in logparser.exe. The problem it that the source file is flat log file and has no header. Even if I change the input file to TEXTLINE instead of TSV, still does not work.